# How to generate a pseudo random number based on previous number in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics

Am attempting to run a monte carlo simulation using numpy like so:

```
from numpy import random

btcpremiummean = -2.61
btcpremiumsd = 1.63
trialsize = 1000000

for x in range(trialsize):
    btcpremium = random.normal(btcpremiummean, btcpremiumsd)
    ...
```

I derived the mean and standard deviations from backtests and am using them to generate random figures.

However, though the data fits within this normal distribution, the real-life btcpremium is not truly random; rather it's usually equal to or close to the previous btcpremium.

I can't think of how to how to change my code so that btcpremium values fit within the normal distribution currently used while being affected by previous data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your main problem is to generate a f... load of random numbers without looping through the same sequence, maybe you'll be interested in just streaming them from http://qrng.anu.edu.au/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're generating independent observations, when you need to capture the "close to the previous" behavior.  You seem to be describing an [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), in particular an AR(1) process.  If your next value is related to/dependent on k prior values, it would be an AR(k) process.